# Schema-less table models with EF6 code first from database + Dynamic schema

Tags: entity-framework, schema

I have a situation with multiple Dev/Test/Prod databases + Dev has a different schema name, with structure largely the same as test and prod.

I'd like to create code first DbContext with table classes void of schema name(in the Table attribute) and supply the schema at run time.

I have no code sample since the whole DbContext is generated by wizard, but this is what I'm trying to avoid:

```
[Table("LOC.MY_TABLE")]
public partial class MY_TABLE
```

Comment: Use fluent mapping. Only option.

Comment: Thanks that was the trick, I added the HasSchema and removed schema string from Table attribute in the fluent setup.